# High Load Average:Red Hat Linux: 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64: VMware Platform

Tags: linux, load-average

I virtual machine running red hat Linux and most of the time we see high load average on the machine causing interruption of services.

04:24:08 up 248 days, 11:14,  3 users,  load average: 142.04, 79.86, 64.41
04:27:23 up 248 days, 11:18,  2 users,  load average: 22.99, 58.10, 59.56

All the VMs are running on VMware virtual platform.

Any Idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can have different reasons. I suggest you to check if there is also iowait. Also look for processes that are in D state. On my environment, mostly high load avarage tracked with these symptoms.

Comment: I do not see any processes in D state, iowait is also looking fine on the system.%user is high most of the times.

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
                 18.40    0.01    5.69          3.05     0.00      72.85

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          58.55    0.00   17.81    0.05    0.00   23.58

Answer (score 0):

Gather following diagnostics:

1. top
2. mpstat with /usr/bin/mpstat -P ALL
3. iostat with iostat
4. Top 5 memory hungry processes ps auxxx --sort=-rss | head -6
5. Top cpu hungry processes ps auxxx --sort=-%cpu | head -6